# Solving set of GCD Equations

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following problem to solve:
given $P_i$ the set of first 20 primes (that is i=1,2,...20). find m so that $GCD(5+18m,P_i)=1$ ; 
and
$GCD(7+18m,P_i)=1 $
How should I best approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,P\,$ be the product of all those primes $> 7$ and $\,m = 3P^2$.

If $\,p\neq 5,7\,$ then $\,p\mid 18m,\, p\nmid 5\,$ so $\,p\nmid 5+18m.\,$ Simlarly $\,p\nmid 7+18m.\,$

If $\,p = 5\,$ then $\,5\nmid m\,\Rightarrow\, 5\nmid 5+18m,\,$ and $\,5\mid 7+18m\iff \!\bmod 5\!:\,\ m\equiv -7/18\equiv 3/3\equiv  1$ hence $\, 1\equiv m \equiv 3P^2\Rightarrow\, 3\,$ is a square mod $5$, contradiction. Similarly for $\,p=7.\,$

Comment: Thanks a lot. $m=3P^2$ is one potential answer. Look at the question this way: if I have two GCD equations, like $GCD(x,p_i)=1$ and $GCD(y,p_i)=1 $, where $p_i$ are range of primes, is there a systematic way to combine the two GCD equations and formulate everything in terms of one variable, say Z instead of  two equations in terms of x and y?

Comment: @bijankarimi If you seek to generalize your question then you need to be more specific than that, i.e. you need to include the specific form of $x$ and $y$. Similar methods to the above will work.

Comment: OK, let me go step by step and rephrase the question: if I have two GCD equations with common variable $m$ as follow: $GCD(m,p_i)=1$ and $GCD(m+7,p_i)=1$ where $p_i$ takes values from the first 20 prime numbers. can the two GCD equations be combined (since they both share second argument $p_i$)? my target is to get all potential values of m (in a given range, say from 1 to 1000). I thought if we can combine the two GCD equations into one GCD equation (for each $p_i$) then we have probably good base to calculate all values of m.

Comment: @bijankarimi You should pose another question if you are also interested in generalizations (don't change the current question, but you can refer to it in the new question).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I followed your advice.