# solving-set-of-gcd-equations (continued discussion)

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations, gcd-and-lcm

With reference to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395952/solving-set-of-gcd-equations), I am trying to generalize my previous question here.

If I have two GCD equations with common variable $m$ as follow: $GCD(m,p_i)=1$ and $GCD(m+7,p_i)=1$  where $p_i$ takes values from the first 20 prime numbers. can the two GCD equations be combined (since they both share second argument $p_i$)?

My target is to get all potential values of $m$ (in a given range, say from 1 to 1000). I thought if we can combine the two GCD equations into one GCD equation (for each $p_i$) then we have probably good base to calculate all values of m.

Comment: $\gcd(m,p_i)=1$ and $\gcd(m+7,p_i)=1$ combine to give $\gcd(m(m+7),p_i)=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, OH yes, this is allowed! thanks a lot.!